# Numerically computing an oscillatory integral

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-transform, matlab, computational-mathematics, oscillatory-integral

I want to numerically compute integrals of the form
$$F(s) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^A \frac{e^{isu}}{1 + B\cos(r u)}\,du$$
for fixed $A,r>0, 1 > B >0$ for a finite number of values of $s\in \mathbb{R}$. I am familiar with the Filon method to deal with the highly oscillating case ($|s|\gg 1$). However, I am also concerned with the evaluations with slow oscillations ($0 < |s| \ll 1$), and I'm not sure if Filon method will be enough as it failed in several instances. Is it enough to do a naive approach of applying Filon method for large frequencies, otherwise use the default integral command?

Comment: By curiosity, why do you need to integrate this "multi-singular" function ?

Comment: The denominator is oscillatory, too, especially if $|B|$ is near $1$. What is known about $r$ or thr ratio of $s$ and $r$?  Is $A$ related to the period of numerator or denominator? What are the "several instance" where the Filon method failed? Without detailed information, you can't expect meaningful answers, I'm afraid.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was trying to compute a reproducing kernel for a certain Hilbert space, and sadly it has a lot of piecewise components. I settled for a way to at least compute this kernel at any point, and it turns out that I can simplify the numerical computations if either I have a closed formula for $F$ or at least a reliable way to compute $F$ for any $s$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector yeah, that is true. I assume nothing about the ratios of $s$ and $r$. I tried the standard Filon method where you essentially solve a Vandermonde system and for large $s$, everything works fine, but as soon as I take $0 < s < 1$, I encountered warnings as well as a large incorrect output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might write this as a series in powers of $B$, which converges since $0 < B < 1$:

$$ F(s) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-B)^k \int_0^A e^{isu}  \cos(ru)^k\; du $$
where each term can be computed in closed form.

Comment: This agrees to one of my computations. By expressing cosine in terms of complex exponentials, you will get a double sum involving powers of $-B$, a binomial factor, and modulations of the cardinal sine function. Moreover, one can show that the partial sums converge at a geometric rate (in terms of $|B|$). I was just thinking if I could numerically evaluate this in Matlab without the series expansions. But anyway I guess I should just stick to this as I don't have to take cases on $s$.